# Sequences and Series - AP and GP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question:
If a,b,c are in GP and 
$$a^{1/x} = b^{1/y} = c^{1/z}$$
prove that x,y,z are in AP

I tried writing b and c in terms of a, by assuming a common ratio r, however, I was unable to proceed from there. To prove that x,y,z are in AP, I would most likely need to satisfy the condition $x + y = 2z$. Not sure how I would do that. Please help!

Comment: If $p,q,r$ is a GP, what equality holds true?

Comment: $pr = q^2$ @almagest

Comment: So that leads you to the solution which two people have already provided before you had a chance to think about it!

Comment: @almagest I noticed, but also noticed that I had a comment. Didn't look at the answers until I tried. I managed to get the answer by myself. Thanks for the hint! :D

Comment: Excellent! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle a^{1/x} = b^{1/y} = c^{1/z}=d\implies a=d^x$ etc.

For non-trivial case, $d\ne0$

As $\displaystyle ac=b^2\implies d^{x+z}=(d^y)^2\implies d^{x+z-2y}=1$ assuming  $d\ne0$

Now if $u^m=1$

either $u=1$

or $m=0,u\ne0$

or $u=-1,m$ is even

Comment: you answered seconds before me.. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have $ac=b^2$.
Also, $a=b^{x/y}$ and $c=b^{z/y}$.

So, $ac=b^2$ gives that $b^{x/y+z/y}=b^2$, which means $x+z=2y$

Answer (score 1):

If $a, b, c$ are in GP, then 
$$\begin{align}\frac ba &=\frac cb\\
b^2&=ac\\
b^2&=b^\frac xy \cdot b^\frac zy\\&=b^{\frac xy+\frac zy}\\
2&=\frac xy +\frac zy\\
2y&=x+z\\
y-x&=z-y\end{align}$$
i.e. $x, y, z$ are in AP.